# Creating multiple files after receiving a queue message

Tags: java, queue, message-handlers

I have a project that reads from mongodb and sends that information to the queue. my listener picks up the queue message from cloud. I am able to create a .txt file that inputs all the information inside from the queue. My problem that I have been searching for is: How can I sort through a specific field inside the POJO (IBusiness1,IBusiness2,IBusiness3)and create the file for each? The following code allows me to create only 1 txt file and it does not sort the field:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PaymentPortalBatchListenerApplication.class, args);
    }

    private class MessageHandler implements IMessageHandler {
        private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MessageHandler.class);

        public CompletableFuture<Void> onMessageAsync(IMessage message) {
            System.out.println("received "+message.getBody());
            ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
            PortalList auditList = null;

            try {
                auditList = om.readValue( message.getBody(), PortalList.class );
                System.out.println( "**Audit Message   " + auditList );
                logger.info( "Creating file");
                String exportFilePath = "C:\\filewriter\\IBusiness1 " + 
                LocalDateTime.now().format(formatter) + ".txt";
                File file = new File(exportFilePath);
                FileWriter writeToFile = new FileWriter(file);
                String exportFileHeader = "CREATE_DTTM|FNAME|LNAME|IBusiness";
                StringHeaderWriter headerWriter = new 
                StringHeaderWriter(exportFileHeader);
                writeToFile.write(exportFileHeader);
                writeToFile.write( String.valueOf( headerWriter));
                writeToFile.write( String.valueOf(auditList));
                writeToFile.flush();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

//          System.out.println(auditList);
            return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(null);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did:

PaymentPortalBean = POJO 
auditlist =on-prem copy of PPB

PortalList =

```
    import lombok.Data;

import java.util.List;

@Data
public class PortalList{

    private List<PaymentPortalBean> portalList;
}
```

answer to creating files:

```
         for(PaymentPortalBean bean: auditList.getPortalList()) {
                if(bean.RxBusiness().contains( "IBusiness")){
                    File file = new File( exportFilePath );
                    FileWriter writeToFile = new FileWriter( file );
                    String exportFileHeader = CREATE_DTTM|FNAME|LNAME|IBusiness";
                    writeToFile.write( exportFileHeader );
                    writeToFile.write( String.valueOf(bean));
                    writeToFile.flush();
                }
```

that worked to to find IBusiness, I created two more conditional statements for the types I needed. runs fine.
Mongo db was able to separate the fields I needed.